# openni_launch pointclouds not published in rviz

Tags: rviz, roboearth, openni-launch, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
openni_launch when ran gives the following error

```
[ERROR] [1324070131.410127857]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1324070131.419698718]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
```

As given in the http://answers.ros.org/question/3210/complaint-from-openni_launch-on-already-advertised assuming that it doesn't make an impact i checked the rviz.
I can see the image but the pointcloud is not being visualized.
Even the status is "ok" for the pointcloud2 display in rviz.
I echoed the topic that is subscribed by the rviz on the command line and could see the point clouds being displayed.
Can someone tell what i am missing here.
I saw in some posts that a dynamic reconfigure has to be done for this node. In that case how do i do it.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12377/openni_launch-pointclouds-not-published-in-rviz/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-20**:
Any help on this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably still have an earlier instance running, which `roscore` knows about.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-25**:
any comments on the issue??

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-17**:
When i am not running the roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch the rosservice list is showing "ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!" So i don c anyother instance running. I feel that the openni.launch is advertising the same thing twice but dont kno which code to check for the same.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-17**:
Try `rosservice list`, I suppose. Only one node can advertise a given service. That is what the launch is complaining about.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-16**:
Can you tell how to check that? I don have any other instance as such. But even in that case if rostopic is able to echo that, why is it not subscribed by rviz.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-17**:
If the roscore is being started by roslaunch, it will terminate when the launch does. You can avoid that by running it separately, *before* roslaunch.